# Aptana install problem with Linux (CentsOS 5)

Tags: linux, aptana, centos5

After I installed Aptana (install directory: /usr/share/aptana )

I keep getting errors like this:

> An SWT Error has occurred, you are
>   recommended to exit the workbench.
>   Subsequent errors may happen and
>   terminate the workbench without
>   warning.  See the .log file for more
>   details.

looking in the logs I see this:

> !MESSAGE No more handles
>   (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /root/.Aptana/Aptana
>   Studio/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/72/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3236.so:
>   libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)
>
> ```
> !STACK 0
>
> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
> ```
>
> (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /root/.Aptana/Aptana
>   Studio/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/72/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3236.so:
>   libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)

Well after search the forums and other sites for about an hour, people suggested I install these packages.

```
* yum install gtk2-devel
* yum install xulrunner
* yum install libstdc*
* yum install gtk2*
* yum install libswt3-gtk2*
* yum install compat-libstdc++-33
```

I had some already installed and I don't know if they are really required but there they are for you.

After all that it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across  [this post](http://support.aptana.com/asap/browse/STU-1565). in the post it has a file you need to download called [aptana.sh](http://support.aptana.com/asap/secure/attachment/10969/aptana.sh).

Here is the code if the file is not available:

```
/*************** START OF FILE **************/

#!/bin/bash

# Set path for the Mozilla SWT binding

MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME%*/}
if false && [ -n "$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME" -a -e $MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
:
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla
elif [ -e /usr/lib/firefox/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/firefox
elif [ -e /usr/lib/xulrunner/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla-firefox/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla-firefox
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla
else
$DIALOGW \
--title="Integrated browser support not working" \
--text="This Eclipse build doesn't have support for the integrated browser."
[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit 1
fi
# libraries from the mozilla choosen take precedence
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# Do the actual launch of Aptana Studio
exec ./AptanaStudio


/*************** END OF FILE **************/
```

Still didn't work so I decided to see if the file it was trying to call existed. the command for the file name in:

locate libgtkembedmoz.so

it found it so I added the condition to the script and now it works great, YEAH!!

`elif [ -e /usr/lib/esc-1.0.0/xulrunner/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/esc-1.0.0/xulrunner`

Let me know of any other findings that might help out.

Thanks,
--Phill

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not seem to have the libgtkembedmoz.so file anywhere out of the box.

You can install kompozer and use it.

```
sudo apt-get install kompozer

export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/kompozer
```

Comment: After (unsuccesfully) trying all the other things, I can say using kompozer worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used the Create a Launcher application on desktop and download the

- yum install gtk2-devel
- yum install xulrunner
- yum install libstdc*
- yum install gtk2*
- yum install libswt3-gtk2*
- yum install compat-libstdc++-33

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after much digging around I found that Aptana needs libgtkembedmoz.so to run (Aptana team please fix this, just include the file in the next build please!!!).

Work around:

Well xulrunner (the new version) doesn't include libgtkembedmoz.so file. So after much Googling I found that Thunderbird does. So I YUM install thunderbird and went to check if the file libgtkembedmoz.so was there. (BTW: thunderbird version 2.0.0.18 on CentOS 5). Yeah it's there.

So I have a script that looks for the libgtkembedmoz.so file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set path for the Mozilla SWT binding
MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=${MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME%*/}
if false && [ -n "$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME" -a -e $MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
:
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla
elif [ -e /usr/lib/firefox/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/firefox
elif [ -e /usr/lib/xulrunner/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner
elif [ -e /usr/lib/esc-1.0.0/xulrunner/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/esc-1.0.0/xulrunner
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla-firefox/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla-firefox
elif [ -e /usr/lib/mozilla/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla
elif [ -e /usr/lib/thunderbird-2.0.0.18/libgtkembedmoz.so ]; then
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/thunderbird-2.0.0.18
else
$DIALOGW \
--title="Integrated browser support not working" \
--text="This Eclipse build doesn't have support for the integrated browser."
[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit 1
fi

# libraries from the mozilla choosen take precedence
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# Do the actual launch of Aptana Studio
exec ./AptanaStudio
```

make it executable (chmod 755 scriptname) and run.

Note:

Just cjeck to make sure you have the right version of the program and/or that the path works.

`[user@machine]# ls /usr/lib/thunderbird-2.0.0.18/libgtkembedmoz.so
/usr/lib/thunderbird-2.0.0.18/libgtkembedmoz.so`

So if you have thunerbird 2.0.0.14 please make the change in the script as well.

Hope this help ;-)